# Add custom validations before order placement

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, validation

I am following the Magento documentation to add some validation before creating the order (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html) but I want to do the validation in server side:

**1. Create the validator:**
/view/frontend/web/js/model/custom-validation.js

```
define(
    ['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            /**
             * Validate something
             *
             * @returns {boolean}
             */
            validate: function() {
                //Put your validation logic here
                var customurl = '<?php echo $block->getUrl('module/Controller/Index/Validator');?>';
                $.ajax({
                    url: customurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        customdata1: 'test1',
                        customdata2: 'test2',
                    },
                complete: function(response) {             
                    var validation = response.responseJSON.success;
                    console.log(response);
                    if (validation == true){
                        return true;
                    }  
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**2. Add validator to the validators pool:**
/view/frontend/web/js/view/add-validator.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        '<your_module>/js/model/custom-validation.js'
    ],
    function (Component, additionalValidators, yourValidator) {
        'use strict';
        additionalValidators.registerValidator(yourValidator);
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

**3. Own controller:** vendor/module/Controller/Index/Validator.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory;

class Validator extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    protected $httpClientFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
     * @param HttpClientFactory $httpClientFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        HttpClientFactory $httpClientFactory
        )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        $this->httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $backUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account');//You can give any url, or current page url


        //if controller request is not ajax type
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($backUrl);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        //Get Params
        $customData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customdata1', false);

        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())) 
        {
            $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

            /*Get information from other API*/
            try {
                $url = 'URL_TO_CUSTOM_API';
                $token = 'TOKEN_API';
                $data['parameter'] = $customData;

                $client = $this->_httpClientFactory->create();
                $client->setUri($url);
                $client->setConfig(['timeout' => 300]);
                $client->setHeaders(['Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token]);
                $client->setMethod(\Zend_Http_Client::GET);
                $client->setRawData(json_encode($data));

                try {
                    $responseBody = $client->request()->getBody();
                    $responseJson = json_decode($responseBody, true);
                    /*
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($responseBody);
                    die;*/
                    $resultJson->setData([
                       'success' => true,
                       'error' => false}]);

                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return $resultJson->setData([
                    'success' => false,
                    'error' => $e->getMessage()
                    ]);
                }

                /*$resultJson->setData([
                    'success' => true],
                    'error' => false);*/

            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                return $resultJson->setData([
                    'success' => false,
                    'error' => $e->getMessage()
                    ]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $resultJson->setData([
                    'success' => false,
                    'error' => $e->getMessage()
                    ]);
            }


        }
        //return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

I'm on the right path?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know is late but just for the record, an ajax call is asynchronous so in your example you will always return false.

You can try using promises but I am not sure how they can fit in the provided validators.

PS: Also this point is left: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html#layout